# jQuery find input type (but also for select)

Tags: jquery, select, tagname

I need to find the input type for radio buttons, text, and selects. Its easy to find the input type of anything with `<input type="x">` since `$(this).attr("type")` would return `x`

My issue is that I need to support `<select>` elements, which dont have the type attribute. The end goal is to do return either radio, text, or select.

I thought of doing something like this, but I was curious if there's a better way:

```
if ($(this).tagName == "input") {
    var result = $(this).attr("type");   //returns radio or text (the attr type)
} else {
    var result = $(this).tagName;        //returns select (the element type)
}
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can do this ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vm9Py/152/)), make some sort of easy to use plugin:

```
$.fn.getType = function(){ return this[0].tagName == "INPUT" ? this[0].type.toLowerCase() : this[0].tagName.toLowerCase(); }
```

And use it like this

```
$(".element").getType(); // Will return radio, text, checkbox, select, textarea, etc (also DIV, SPAN, all element types)
$(".elList").getType(); // Gets the first element's type
```

Which will get the type of the first element which is selected.

**Other info**

If you just want to have some selectors you can use this:

```
$("input:text, input:radio, select");
```

Or select all form controls ([more info](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)):

```
$(":input") // can return all form types
```

Answer (score 10):

**All types of input box and select box getting together by jQuery find :**

```
$('#myForm').find('select,input').each(function(i,box){
     alert($(box).attr('name'));
}
```