# jquery - get input and select elements with id start and ends with

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have found how to get the elements whose id starts with `aName` and ends with `EditMode` as below: [jQuery selector for matching at start AND end of ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1142687/3770885)

`$('[id ^=aName][id $=EditMode]')`

I have also found how to get the elements of type input and select as below: [jQuery find input type (but also for select)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9116746/3770885)

`$('input,  select');`

How can I combine both these to get all the input and select elements whose ids start with `aName` and end with `EditMode`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-selector)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
$('input, select').filter('[id^=aName][id$=EditMode]')....
```

OR, Combine selectors

```
$('input[id^=aName][id$=EditMode], select[id^=aName][id$=EditMode]').....
```

Comment: Using filter is probably the best way :) also good to note: tagname selectors are more efficient than attribute selectors, so always select by tagname first, and then filter using attributes: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533285/jquery-select-by-class-vs-select-by-attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`jquery filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
$('input,select').filter('[id ^=aName][id $=EditMode]')
```

See demo below:

```js
console.log($('input,select').filter('[id ^=aName][id $=EditMode]').get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="aName_1_EditMode"/>
<input type="text" id="aName_2_EditMode"/>
<input type="text" id="aName_3_EditMode"/>
<input type="text" id="aName_3_"/>
<input type="text" id="3_EditMode"/>

<select type="text" id="aName_4_EditMode">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```